# Any better suggestions to debug iOS FileProvider extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fileprovider-extension, files-app

I'm working on a document-based app and hence also working on the FileProvider extension for the app, as Apple suggests it

I've pretty much achieved all the basic functionalities for the extension(listing, previewing files, performing certain user-actions and stuff)

So far, to debug the extension, I'll either attach it to process(from the 'Debug' menu) or run the FileProvider scheme through the Files app. Both of these methods are usable only to an extent and results in a 'frozen Files app' after a couple of tries. (Breakpoints don't work properly too, at times)

I'll have to restart my device or force-quit Xcode for this to work again(every couple or more tries!) and this is so annoying!!
(Files app bug?!)

Is there a fix or some better way to debug the extension? I've tried the same with multiple devices just to ensure if I'm not the only one but happens on every single device I tried

Comment: Show us some code, plz! Maybe you're blocking the main thread completely? Hard to tell without your code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your response!

I don't have any problems with code.

All of these start when I try to debug my code to better understand the process(callbacks at places and stuff).

All I need is to know is if there is a better debugging solution/method available for the extension

Comment: And when I'm talking about Files app getting frozen, it's the whole app itself and not just my section of the app(maybe that's why you're confused with threading and all)